# DefaultCellTableRenderer with collored Cells dosnt work with TableRowSorter?

Tags: java, swing

I´m trying to use a DefaultTableCellRenderer with a simple TableRowSorter.

My model looks ok and works. My render looks ok and works with my model. Even to draw icon in the cell I need.

But, when I try to apply a TableRowSorter. it only works if I remove my renderer.
I mean. When i apply the renderer. The table does not sort when the user clicks.
If i dont use the Renderer. The sorter works just fine. Including the "integer" order.

Basically they are excluding each other for working.

I´ve been trying diferrent solutions for over 5 days with no results. I proball missing something so basic that I just cant tell.

Heres my code.

**Table model:**

```
    package model;

    import control.PaisDAO;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

    /**
     *
     * @author X8
     */
    public class PaisTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Pais> elements;
        private String[] columnNames = {"Pais", "Abrev", "Descrição", "Icone"};

        /**
         * Construtor recebe dados iniciais em formato de ArrayList Pais
         *
         * @param elements
         */
        public PaisTableModel(List<Pais> elements) {

            this.elements = elements;

        }

        /**
         * numero de linhas de sua tabela. Metodo obrigatorio herdado e reescrito.
         *
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            //numero de linhas/elementos.
            return elements.size();
        }

        /**
         * Numero de colunas de nossa tabela. de 0 a 3 = 4 colunas.
         *
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 4; //numero de colunas da tabela
        }

        /**
         * Retorna o valor a ser preenchido na linha e coluna
         *
         * @param row
         * @param col
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            //retornar os dados das linhas/celulas
            Pais p = elements.get(row);
            if (col == 0) {
                return p.getPais();
            }
            if (col == 1) {
                return p.getAbreviado();
            }
            if (col == 2) {
                return p.getDescricao();
            }
            if (col == 3) {
                return p.getIcone();
            }
            return null;

        }

        /**
         * Define o nome de cabecalho da coluna
         *
         * @param col
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {

            return columnNames[col];
        }

        /**
         * Apresenta a tabela qual tipo de dados ela deve desenhar
         *
         * @param col
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {

            if (col == 0) {
                return Integer.class;
            }
            if (col == 1 || col == 2) {
                return String.class;
            }

            return super.getColumnClass(col);
        }

        /**
         * Retorna o objeto inteiro para facilitar pegar uma linha inteira
         *
         * @param row
         * @return
         */
        public Pais get(int row) {
            return elements.get(row);
        }

        /**
         * Permitir adicionar uma linha unica
         *
         * @param p
         */
        public void add(Pais p) {
            elements.add(p);
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        /**
         * Adicionar colecao de itens ao final da lista.
         *
         * @param itens
         */
        public void addAll(List<Pais> itens) {
            elements.addAll(itens);
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        /**
         * Limpa a tabela toda.
         */
        public void clear() {
            elements.clear();
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

    } //EOF
```

Table Renderer:

```
    package model;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

    /**
     *
     * @author X8
     */
    public class PaisesTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public PaisesTableRenderer() {
            this.setOpaque(true);
        }


        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object
  item, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

            //usar get configurado no TableModel para pegar o objeto inteiro.
            PaisTableModel modelo=(PaisTableModel) jtable.getModel();
            Pais p=modelo.get(row);
            //colore linhas espacadas e selecionada

            if (isSelected ){
                this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                if (row % 2 == 0){
                    this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    this.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                } else {
                    this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            } 

            //escreve texto, icone e define tamanho de cada coluna
            if (col==0){
                this.setText(Integer.toString(p.getPais()));
                this.setIcon(null);
               jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(100);
            }
            if (col==1){
                this.setText(p.getDescricao());
                this.setIcon(null);
               jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(400);
            }
            if (col==2){
                this.setText(p.getAbreviado());
                this.setIcon(null);
               jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(100);
            }
            if (col==3){
                this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(p.getIcone()));
                this.setText("");
               jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(100);
                //this.setText(p.getIcone());
            }

            return this;
        }



        @Override
        public void updateUI() {
            super.updateUI();
        }

        @Override
        public void repaint() {
            super.repaint(); 
        }

    }
```

Adding the table row sorter, model and renderer to the table:

```
tbPaises.setModel(new PaisTableModel(dbPaises.asArrayList()));

        //tbPaises.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new     
PaisesTableCellRenderer2());

        //tbPaises.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>
(tbPaises.getModel());  
        //sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        tbPaises.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PaisTableModel modelo=(PaisTableModel) jtable.getModel();
Pais p=modelo.get(row);
```

A sorter does NOT change the order of the data in the TableModel. Only the view of the data is changed.

Renderers deal with indexes of the table, not the TableModel, so if you want to access the data from the TableModel you need to convert the "table row" to the "model row":

```
int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row) 
PaisTableModel modelo = (PaisTableModel)jtable.getModel();
Pais p = modelo.get(modelRow);
```

The other option is to just get the data from the JTable using the `getValueAt(...)` method. The table will then do the index conversion automatically for you.

Actually, your renderer should not even have all the "if conditions". The `getValueAt(...)` method of the TableModel will return the appropriate value to display. The first statement in the renederer should be:

```
super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
```

You can also check out [Table Row Renderering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an easier approach to alternate row colors so you don't even need to create a custom renderer.

Also, don't override updateUI() or repaint(). There is no reason to override those methods.

Comment: Thank you alot. really. . I´ve readed some about view x model in tables but didn´t get it yet. I´m changing the code

Comment: Thank you alot. really. . I´ve read some about view x model in tables but didn´t get it yet. now it works just fine. I didn´t understand the getvalueAt thing. I mean. Where should I use it?